# Is there a way to configure VLC to remember which video I was on when I open a folder?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, video-playback

Basically every time I open VLC, I manually open the folder which contains the videos (episodes from a show) that I am watching and then manually select the video I was watching the last time I closed VLC. I want to know if there is a way to make VLC remember this for me because a lot of the times I forget which video I was on. If I should be doing this some other way then please suggest that as well. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

Media->Open Recent Media
.......

Comment: This has never worked on Mac. The Recents… menu is always empty.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this option does not do what I am looking for. It only adds the video I was last watching to my playlist so that once it finishes I have to open the next video again from the folder manually. I want to know if there is a way to have all the episodes open in the form of a playlist and playback resume from wherever I left off last time.

Comment: I get round this, practically, by never quitting the app & never rebooting the Mac its running on. If I have to reboot for whatever reason, I set up appropriate open folders & tagged files [which I'm aware Windows cannot do] before reboot so I can just re-drop my upcoming 'to watch' from the appropriate point. That means I almost never use saved playlists, as they don't really gain anything. I'd love it if VLC eventually got round to using the Mac-toolbox standard of being able to re-launch after quit or reboot in exactly the same state as when quit. Almost all Mac apps can do that these days.